# Express / React - In production, my axios requests contains my index.html file in response and don't reach my express server api routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I did some research and found similar posts with this problem but none of the solutions worked for me.

I've made a React app with create-react-app and then i've created a server.js file to have a Express Node server. I've followed some tutorials and it seems that i can pu my react app and my express server in the same app/build.

In local, everything is working, i reach my api routes. But when i deploy the build of my app on a server, all my axios requests responses are the index.html file off my app. What's the issue in my code that don't allow my axios requests to reach my api ?

Here's the code :

server.js

```
const connection = require("./conf");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.post("/api/user", (req, res) => {
  const formData = req.body;
  connection.query("INSERT INTO user SET ?", formData, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send("Error");
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
  });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, ".build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(8080, () =>
  console.log("Express server is running on localhost:8080")
);
```

Mail.js with axios

```
axios
  .post(
    "/api/user",
    {
      email: "xxx",
      name: "xxx"
    },
    { withCredentials: true }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

and the response from axios

```
{data: "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset…s/main.f398f833.chunk.js"></script></body></html>", status: 200, statusText: ""
```

and in console i have the good url :

```
xhr.js:178 XHR finished loading: POST "https://www.mywebsite.com/api/user".
```

If i put this url in my browser, i have a blank page, like when i put an url which is not in my front-end react router.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Did you put proxy in package.json or set baseURL of axios

Comment: I had a proxy in package.json when i was testing in local, with my localhost and the port. I don't use baseUrl in my axios request. 

I've followed this tutorial : https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-serve-react-from-same-origin/  and they say that the proxy is useless in production build and that i need to put this lines :

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))


 app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')) })
`

 but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Can you tell me if the ui is loading or not

if ui is not loading the it is deployment problem

and if it is loading then try to put this in app.js
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'YOUR_URL';

Comment: The UI is loading without problem. I don't think it's a Axios error because when i use Postman to reach my API routes, i have the same result : the index.html page. 
I added  axios.defaults.baseURL and `const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; ` to my server.js. Then i get a CORS error. I solved this issue but i'm back to the beggining, i can't reach my api routes.

Comment: Having the exact same problem just without using Axios. 
Would love to have the solution if anyone has it